# MySQL Rails Incorrect Datetime value during Daylight Savings Time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, dst

Last year around this time I saw some errors in Airbrake related to daylight savings time in our Rails 5 application. The app was throwing an error while trying to update a model's `updated_at` column:

*ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-11 02:58:48' for column 'updated_at'*

I can reproduce this by manually setting the `updated_at` attribute and then calling `save!`.

The app and server time zone are set to UTC. During daylight savings the hour between two and three o'clock should effectively disappear.. why is my app trying to set this value as a timestamp?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody here know why your app is trying to do this. We do not have enough information about it. However, I prefer to update such timestamps without using any data that client sent you. You can change the column's default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if your MySQL version allow it or use on insert/update triggers: `SET NEW.updated_at = NOW();`

Comment: It sounds like MySQL is in strict mode.